# Grid com gráficos que substituem um ao outro

Tags: html, css, gráfico, grid

Estou criando uma página com um grid que deve ter 3 gráficos, um em cada posição do grid. Mas todos os gráficos ficam em uma mesma posição do grid e acabam substituindo os gráficos anteriores (o gráfico 2 substitui o gráfico 1, e o 3 substitui os gráficos 1 e 2). Como corrijo isso? Seguem os códigos abaixo:

```css
fieldset{
border: 1px solid #6f3658;
}

#fieldG {
font-family: 'Century Gothic';
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
width: 900px;
margin: auto;
} 

.titGraf {
font-family: 'Bahnschrift Condensed';
text-align: center;
padding: auto;
}
.row {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 33.3% 33.3% 33.3%;
grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
grid-template-areas: "." "." ".";
}
#g1.highcharts-figure, #G1.highcharts-data-table table {
min-width: 310px; 
max-width: 800px;
margin: 1em auto;
}

#G1#container1 {
height: 400px;
}

#G1.highcharts-data-table table {
  font-family: 'Bahnschrift';
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

#G1.highcharts-data-table th {
  font-weight: 600;
padding: 0.5em;
}
#G1.highcharts-data-table td, #G1.highcharts-data-table th, #G1.highcharts-data-table caption {
padding: 0.5em;
} 

#G1.highcharts-data-table thead tr, #G1.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
 background: #f8f8f8;
}

#G1.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
background: #f1f7ff;
}

#G2.highcharts-figure, #G2.highcharts-data-table table {
min-width: 320px; 
max-width: 660px;
margin: 1em auto;
}

#G2.highcharts-data-table table {
  font-family: 'Bahnschrift';
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
 } 

#G2.highcharts-data-table caption {
padding: 1em 0;
font-size: 1.2em;
color: #555;
}
#G2.highcharts-data-table th {
  font-weight: 600;
padding: 0.5em;
}
#G2.highcharts-data-table td, #G2.highcharts-data-table th, #G2.highcharts-data-table caption {
padding: 0.5em;
}
#G2.highcharts-data-table thead tr, #G2.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
background: #f8f8f8;
}
#G2.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
background: #f1f7ff;
}

#G3.highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
min-width: 310px; 
max-width: 800px;
margin: 1em auto;
}

#G3#container {
height: 400px;
}

#G3.highcharts-data-table table {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}
#G3.highcharts-data-table caption {
 padding: 1em 0;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #555;
}
#G3.highcharts-data-table th {
   font-weight: 600;
 padding: 0.5em;
}

#G3.highcharts-data-table td, #G3.highcharts-data-table th, #G3.highcharts-data-table caption {
 padding: 0.5em;
}
#G3.highcharts-data-table thead tr, #G3.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
 background: #f8f8f8;
}

#G3.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Teste2.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset id="fieldG">
        <legend>Bem vindo</legend>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col" id="G1">
                    <fieldset class="graf" id="graf1">
                        <legend class="titGraf" id="grafico1">Gráfico 1</legend>
                        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
                        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
                        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
                        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
                        <figure class="highcharts-figure">
                            <div id="container"></div>
                        </figure>
                        <script>
                            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                                chart: {
                                    type: 'column'
                                    },
                                    title: {
                                        text: 'Gráfico 1'
                                        },
                                        xAxis: {
                                            categories: [
                                                'Item 1',
                                                'Item 2',
                                                'Item 3',
                                                'Item 4',
                                                'Item 5',
                                                'Item 6',
                                                'Item 7',
                                                'Item 8',
                                                'Item 9',
                                                'Item 10',
                                            ],  
                                            crosshair: true
                                        },    
                                        yAxis: {
                                        min: 0, 
                                        title: {
                                        text: 'Gráfico 1'
                                        }
                                        },
                                        tooltip: {
                                        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                                        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                                        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                                        footerFormat: '</table>',
                                        shared: true,
                                        useHTML: true
                                        },
                                        plotOptions: {
                                        column: {
                                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                                        borderWidth: 0
                                        }
                                        },
                                        series: [{
                                            name: 'Quantidade',
                                            data: [13, 10, 7, 5, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1,]
                                        }]
                            });
                        </script>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="col" id="G2">
                    <fieldset class="graf" id="graf2">
                        <legend class="titGraf" id="grafico2">Gráfico 2</legend>
                        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
                        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
                        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
                        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
                        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

                        <figure class="highcharts-figure">
                        <div id="container2"></div>
                        </figure>
                        <script>
                            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                                chart: {
                                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                                    plotShadow: false,
                                    type: 'pie'
                                },
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Gráfico 2'
                                },
                                tooltip: {
                                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                                },
                                accessibility: {
                                    point: {
                                        valueSuffix: '%'
                                    }
                                },
                                plotOptions: {
                                    pie: {
                                        allowPointSelect: true,
                                        cursor: 'pointer',
                                        dataLabels: {
                                            enabled: false
                                    },
                                        showInLegend: true
                                    }
                                },
                                series: [{
                                    name: 'Status',
                                    colorByPoint: true,
                                    data: [{
                                        name: 'Item 1',
                                        y: 35,
                                }, {
                                    name: 'Item 2',
                                    y: 10
                                }, {
                                    name: 'Item 3',
                                    y: 15
                                }, {
                                    name: 'Item 4',
                                    y: 20
                                }, {
                                    name: 'Item 5',
                                    y: 15
                                }, {
                                    name: 'Item 6',
                                    y: 5
                                }]
                            }]
                        });
                    </script>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="col" id="G3">
                    <fieldset class="graf" id="graf3">
                        <legend class="titGraf" id="grafico3">Gráfico 3</legend>
                        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
                        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
                        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
                        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

                        <figure class="highcharts-figure">
                            <div id="container"></div>
                        </figure>
                        <script>
                            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                                chart: {
                                    type: 'column'
                                },
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Preventivas'
                                },
                                xAxis: {
                                    categories: [
                                        'Item 1',
                                        'Item 2',
                                        'Item 3',
                                        'Item 4',   
                                        'Item 5',
                                        'Item 6',
                                        'Item 7',
                                        'Item 8',
                                        'Item 9',
                                        'Item 10',
                                        'Item 11',
                                        'Item 12'
                                    ],
                                    crosshair: true
                                },
                                yAxis: {
                                    min: 0,
                                    title: {
                                        text: 'Gráfico 3'
                                    }
                                },
                                tooltip: {
                                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                                    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                                    footerFormat: '</table>',
                                    shared: true,
                                    useHTML: true
                                },
                                plotOptions: {
                                    column: {
                                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                                        borderWidth: 0
                                    }
                                },
                                series: [{
                                    name: 'Antes',
                                    data: [17, 0, 5, 53, 117, 101, 56, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                                    }, {
                                    name: 'Depois',
                                    data: [17, 0, 5, 54, 109, 74, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                                }]
                            });
                        </script>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título. Sei que é comum em muitos fóruns, mas aqui funciona diferente. Você já marcou uma resposta como aceita (quando clicou no ✓) e isso já é o suficiente para indicar que foi resolvido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está declarando os 3 gráficos na mesma div usando `Highcharts.chart('container',`. Se trocar isso para o nome da div que você quer que o gráfico apareça vai funcionar.

Tem alguns outros erros no seu código de copiar e colar. Tem duas divs com o mesmo id container e você não precisa declarar os scripts em cada div, se pode deixar tudo no header, declarando só uma vez.

Comment: Era isso, mesmo. Resolvido.
Obrigado pela explicação.